# OpenLDAP ACL stored as hash?

Tags: openldap, centos7

Does anyone know why when I add these 3 ACLs the third is represented in the olcDatabase\={2}hdb.ldif as a random string?

ACLs:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by dn="cn=Manager,dc=eastlands,dc=net" write
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=Manager,dc=server,dc=net" write by * read
```

slapcat output:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by dn="cn=Manager,dc=server,dc=net" write
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess:: ezJ9dG8gKiBieSBkbj0iY249TWFuYWdlcixkYz1lYXN0bGFuZHMsZGM9bmV0IiB3cml0ZSBieSAqIHJlYWQg
```

This is kind of random but it's really bugging me.

I'm running openldap-2.4.39-7.el7 on CentOS 7.

Comment: This is the base64 encoding of the string. AFAIK OpenLDAP uses it if runs into some special characters that it thinks are part of the string (eg. CR or LF).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
echo "your_hash" | openssl enc -d -base64
```

you will see what is inside the hash. You can confirm what @Sven said (a trailing space at the end of the line, very likely).

Answer (score 0):

I made this simple script to do that:
https://github.com/peppelinux/slapd_acl

just install it with `pip3 install slapd_acl`
It will show us the ACL in plaintext if they are in b64.
It can also export them in a ldap modify ldif structure, to let us to modify them easily and submit soon after.